# Can’t set array in JavaScript in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, safari, web-inspector

Okay, this is crazy…

I am creating a Cordova iOS / Android app and all the sudden my Safari stopped assigning arrays / objects. In Chrome console it works fine.
I am lost and have no idea how to deal with this.

Is this a memory issue and how do I verify?

- Safari: Version 8.0.8 (10600.8.9)
- Cordova: 5.2.0
- Ionic: 1.6.4

In console I type

```
var a = [1];
a;
```

and it returns `[]`.

Comment: Do you type these separately? Try `a=[1];a;` or `var a=[1];a;` in one line. Does `a[0]` return `1`?

Comment: a=[1];a; returns []
var a=[1];a; returns [] 
but oddly a[0] returns 1

This is a strange behavior. I guess its assigned but it doesn't want to show.

Comment: I've just tryed and I get [1]